# Why is Visual Studio 2017 with Node.JS tools not able to run / debug node.js project?

Tags: javascript

I just installed Node.JS tools for visual studio and created a new  **Blank Node.js Web Application**. Without any other modifications to the project, whenever I click on >Internet explorer or hit the F5 key, a console window displaying **Debugger listening on [::]:5858** appears and that's it, the debug button becomes enabled again and the console window remains open.

I then tried accessing `localhost:1337` (the default port configured both in the project properties and in the code itself) and it tells me the page doesn't exist. I then tried `localhost:8080` and still nothing. The only one that seems to work is `localhost:5858` that only seems to display some debug info.

However, if I choose to **start without debugging** then Visual Studio happily launches the same console window AND the browser which immediately starts to load `localhost:1337` and once it's finished I am greeted by the **"Hello world"** message that the project is written to display.

I tried reinstalling the extension, the entire IDE and finally I tried it on a separate machine that ended up exhibiting the same behavior.

Any clues? Any steps I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Inside your project, right click on the js script and select Set as **Node.js Start up File**

2) Right Click on the Project and click on Debug -> Start New Instance

Your debug session is started.  This procedure is for console project.

Comment: This answer was actually helpful. I would add that you have to right click on your app.js or server.js file.